# Why do I get an #REF! error after sorting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

In my workbook I use this formula:

`=INDEX('G:\Manufacturing\WH\EXPORTS\Scanning_Reports [ScanningReport.xls]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$65536;AB3)`

It works fine but when i try to sort the data i got a `#ref!` error how can i avoid it??

This is the formula in AB3

`=MATCH(K3;'G:\Manufacturing\WH\EXPORTS\Scanning_Reports\[ScanningReport.xls]Sheet1'!$I$1:$I$65536;0)`

When i sort or delete something this one get an #na error dont know why!!
The error will disappear simple by dragging the code.

I believe that this is the problem but i don't know how to fix it

`Excel displays this error to prompt you to correct the formulas yourself so that you don't get unexpected results`

Excel auto corrects the formulas but it gives a #ref to notify me for the changes. The changes are fine.

I found the problem for a strange reason if the ScanningReport.xls is open then everything is fine the problem occurs only when the ScanningReport.xls is closed i you have an idea to solve it please let me know

I use Excel 2010

Comment: Is that file reference (G:\...) a reference to this file or to another Excel file? If that refers to this file you're working in, then it might work better to remove the file parts and just have Sheet1!$D$1:$D$65536;AB3 instead.

Comment: it is another excel file. the problem its not only with sorting but also when i delete a row. Also my vlookup formula doesn't show this eror after sorting

Comment: Is AB3 inside the range you are sorting or is it  affected by the delete? I noticed you don't have $'s on that part of the INDEX function. Or, worst case, create two new simple workbooks to test this and see if you can make it work at all in those documents. If so, figure out what you're doing differently in the "real" files. If the simple test fails, then Excel must not work this way. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your help peter please check again edited some new informations

Comment: Are you running Excel 2003 or below?

Comment: No i am using Excel 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know this until now, but according [to this page on OzGrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=44975), the Excel INDEX function requires the external workbook to be open for it to work properly.

[This page has a reference](http://www.ashishmathur.com/tag/indirect-ext/) to an Addin you can install to Excel 2010 that will give you an INDEX.EXT function, which can work with closed workbooks. Make note of what the author, Ashish Mathur, there says about the performance of using this addin.

Comment: Thanks i was thinkning something like that. Unofrtunately i can not install the addin because i use this file on my work and i am not allowed so i will just leave the other workbook open

Answer (score 1):

Try using whole column references instead of addressing the range from the first to the last row.

```
=MATCH(K3;'G:\Manufacturing\WH\EXPORTS\Scanning_Reports\[ScanningReport.xls]Sheet1'!$I:$I;0)
```

Same for the Index function. It will be more robust when you insert and delete rows.

Are you really using 65 K rows of data? You may want to think about dynamic ranges that limit the lookup range to only the used rows.

Comment: teylyn $I:$I it changes to $I$1:$I$65536 when you apply its the same.I am not familiar with dynamic ranges so if you could post an example it will be helpful. Also from excel help i think that i get the #ref because of this "Excel displays this error to prompt you to correct the formulas yourself so that you don't get unexpected results"

Comment: What version are you running? When I use I1:I65536, albeit in the same sheet, it changes it to I:I with Excel 2003. You can build dynamic ranges in many ways, for example with an offset() function, using a count of cells in a column that has all cells filled in. There are many examples out there.

Comment: I use excel 2010. I found the exact problem please check my question again if you figure out a solution. Thanks